# How to fix unicode error when using re.compile?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, python-re

I wrote a code for removing emojis from string:

```
import re

text = u'This is a bee '
print(text) # with emoji

def de_emojify(text):
    regex_pattern = re.compile(pattern = "["
        u"\U0001F600-\U0001F64F" 
        u"\U0001F300-\U0001F5FF"
        u"\U0001F680-\U0001F6FF"
        u"\U0001F1E0-\U0001F1FF"
                           "]+", flags = re.UNICODE)
    return regex_pattern.sub(r'', text)

print(de_emojify(text))
```

It works well when I use it on colab, but when i do it on Jupyter lab i get this error:

```
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 11-19: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

how to fix it?

Comment: What lines does your error occur at? Usually, there is a pointer to the relevant line for a SyntaxError.

Comment: What OS are you on?

Comment: @9769953 here "[". i am on linux

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GlDA5.png

Comment: @Sabil for too it works well everywhere besides Jupiter lab in linux

Comment: Do you start Jupyter Lab from the command line?

Comment: @9769953 no i dont. i open it by link in browser

Comment: But how is Jupyter Lab started? The server itself should be started somehow.

Comment: The *meaning* of the error is there isn't exactly 8 digits after the `\U` for the escape codes, but they all look correct.  BTW, `re.UNICODE` and `u""` aren't needed on Python 3.